# gradients exploding ,loss nan ,accuracy zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nan

I am getting Nan loss and 0 accuracy . I am using fit_generator Keras for fitting my model. And I don't have any NaNs in my input.

```
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 50, 59, 7000
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16 ,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1), recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.1),      
bias_regularizer=l2(0.1),input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),   metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is how I am fitting my model using custom generators:

```
h1=model.fit_generator(generator(batch_size=batch_size, training_files=training_files,number_of_features=n_features),
                       steps_per_epoch=len(training_files)*500/batch_size,
                       epochs=10,
                       verbose=1,
                       shuffle=True,
                       validation_data=validation_data_generator(batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                                 validation_files=validation_files,
                                                                 number_of_features=n_features),
                       validation_steps=len(validation_files)*500/batch_size,
                       workers=16
                       ,max_queue_size=60,
                       use_multiprocessing=True

                       )
```

Normalization function:

```
def normalize(df):

  header=df.columns
  subid_col=df['SUBJECT_ID']
  label_col=df['label']
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(method="ffill")

  df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)  # 0 to nan
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(df.mean()) #fills nan with mean value
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(0) #whole column nan
  x = df.values

  header=df.columns

  min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (1,2))
  x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
  df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)

  df.columns=header
  df['SUBJECT_ID']=subid_col
  df['label']=label_col
  df.drop(df.columns[0], axis = 1, inplace = True)
  return df
```

Comment: Try reading this thread: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2134 It has helped me with this issue

Comment: check for any corrupted data or 0 length string something similar